Prove that for any natural $m$ there exists natural $k$ such that $m\mid 3^{k+1} - 2^{k} - k$
I'm not sure how to approach this problem, any help is appreciated.
I tried considering it for even and odd $k$, but didn't really get anywhere except showing that it will be even if $k$ is odd.
It does seem to check out for relatively smaller values of $k$ and $m$, so I think the problem might boil down to showing that $3^{k+1} - 2^k - k$ will have infinitely many unique prime factors, thus satisfying the condition? But I'm not sure how one would go about proving that.

What $k$   would work for $m=2?$   And then, where did you get the problem?

actually $k = 1$ satisfies $2 | 3^2 - 2 - 1 = 6$ @WillJagy

As OP notes the expression is even when $k$ is odd, so any odd $k$ will satisfy $2| 3^{k+1}-2^k-k$. That's not the problem, it's all the other natural numbers that pose a challenge.

@Cheese   I make a point of asking  an OP about  the cases with smallest  parameters  when it appears that they have done no such thing, and may not know what the words mean.

Hint: For primes $p$ with $ \gcd(p, 6) = 1$, show that $ k = (p-1)(p-2)$ works. Why does it work? How could we have come up with it without knowing the form initially? How can we extend this ideal to composite numbers? What to do when $ \gcd(m, 6) \neq 1$?

@AntonyTheo (with regards to your deleted solution) It is worth pointing out that just because $a_{k_1} \equiv a_{k_2}$, doesn't mean that a (even if periodic) sequence has period $k_1 - k_2$. EG take $ a_i \equiv 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3,3,  \ldots$. However, it will have (at least) the original period (which is 5 in this example).

This math problem can be reasonably attacked by letting $~m~$ take on each value in (for example) $~{2,3,4,\cdots,150},~$ and for each value of $~m,~$ identify all satisfying values of $~k~$ such that (for example) $~k \leq 30.~$  Write a computer program to create the corresponding 2 dimensional chart, examine the data, try to find a pattern in the data, try to form a hypothesis based on the perceived pattern, and then try to prove the hypothesis.

Disclaimer:  I tried searching around, but couldn't find a reasonable duplicate, or an abstract duplicate. This solution is novel to me (at least), so I think it is alright for me to post even if the community has not had enough time processing it in the event that this should truly be closed (it has 1 close vote after 8 hours, but with 5 upvotes). If this is in violation, please let me know and I will delete this solution.
$  $
$ $
$ $
Observation: $ -k \pmod{m}$ is immediately periodic with period $ m$.
Observation: $ 3^{k+1} - 2^k \pmod{m}$ is eventually periodic with period (at most) $ \phi (m)$.
If $ m = 2^s 3^t n$ with $ \gcd(n, 6) = 1$, then the sequence is immediately periodic when restricted to $k \geq \max(s, t)$.
Corollary: $3^{k+1} - 2^k - k \pmod{m}$ is eventually periodic with period (at most) $ m \phi(m)$.
For now, let's assume that $ 3^{k+1} - 2^k \pmod{m}$ is immediately periodic, so that you can easily see the main gist of the solution, without being boggled down with a minor but troublesome detail. If you rather not make this assumption, then skip to the Complete Solution section.
Solution for the case when $ \gcd ( \phi (m) , m) = 1$.
By Chinese Remainder theorem, there always exists a solution to the system
$$ \begin{cases} k  \equiv a & \pmod{ \phi(m) }\\ k \equiv 3^{a+1} - 2^a  & \pmod{m} \end{cases} $$
Then, for this solution $k$, we have
$$ 3^{k+1} - 2^k  - k \equiv 3^{a+1} - 2^{a} - (3^{a+1} - 2^{a}) \equiv 0 \pmod{m} .$$
Corollary: This system is both necessary and sufficient, so considering $k \pmod{m\phi(m)}$, we have exactly $\phi(m)$ solutions corresponding to each value of $a$.
Corollary: If $ k $ is a solution, then so is $ k + qm\phi(m)$ for any positive integer $q$, so we have infinitely many solutions.
Corollary: (See the hint in my comment) Let $m$ be a prime $ p \geq 5$. Then,

$\phi(p) = p-1$ so $ \gcd( \phi(p) , p ) = 1$ so we are in this case.
The assumption that $ 3^{k+1} - 2^k \pmod{m}$ is immediately periodic is satisfied for any $ \gcd(p, 6) = 1$ since $ \max(s, t) = 0$, so this is a valid proof.

Hence, we may take $ a = 0$ (any other integer value works too), and consider the system
$$ \begin{cases} k \equiv 0 & \pmod{p-1} \\ k\equiv 3^{0+1} - 2^ 0 \equiv 2 & \pmod{p} \end{cases}.$$
which yield $k= (p-1)(p-2)$ as a solution.
Solution for the case when $ \gcd(\phi(m), m) = d \neq 1$:
Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that for there to be a solution, it is necessary and sufficient that the remainders agree modulo $d$: $a \equiv 3^{a+1} - 2^a \pmod{d}$.
Does such an $a$ exist?
Let's use strong induction on the problem statement that for $m$, there exists a $k$ such that $ m \mid 3^{k+1} - 2^k - k$.
OP says they checked the base cases.
Otherwise, for $m \geq 2$, since $ d = \gcd(\phi(m), m) \leq \phi (m)  < m$, then by the induction hypothesis, there exists an $a$ such that $ d \mid 3^{a+1} - 2^a - a$.
Hence, the system has a solution, for which
$$ 3^{k+1} - 2^k  - k \equiv    3^{a+1} - 2^a - (3^{a+1} - 2^a) \equiv 0 \pmod{m} .$$
Corollary: The set {$ 3^{k+1} - 2^k - k \pmod{m}$} is a complete residue class. To prove that $ 0 \in  3^{k+1} - 2^k - k -n \pmod{m}$, likewise set up
$$ \begin{cases} k  \equiv a  & \pmod{ \phi(m) }\\ k \equiv 3^{a+1} - 2^a -n  & \pmod{m} \end{cases}. $$

Complete solution: Accounting for $ 3^{k+1} - 2^k \pmod{m}$ not being immediately periodic
For $ m = 2^s 3^t n $ with $ \gcd(n, 6) = 1$, we need to ensure that the choice of $a$ is $ \geq \max(s, t)$ in order for the modulo operations to work as desired.
We will prove this stronger statement by strong induction:

For all positive integers $ m = 2^s 3^t n $ with $ \gcd(n, 6) = 1$, there exists a non-negative integer $k$ such that $m \mid 3^{k+1} - 2^k  - k$ and $k \geq \max(s, t) $.
Furthermore, for any positive integer $q$, $ k + qm\phi(m)$ also satisfies the conditions.

Base case of $m = 1$ is true with $k = 0 \geq 0 = \max(s, t)$.
For any integer of the form $ K = 1 + q \times 1 \times 1$, $ 1 \mid 3^{K+1} - 2^K - K $.
Base case of $m = 2$ is true with $k = 1 \geq 1 = \max(s, t)$.
For any integer of the form $ K =1 + q \times 2 \times 1$, as OP commented for odd $K$, we have $ 2 \mid 3^{K+1} - 2^K - K$.
Induction step: Suppose the statement is true for all values $< m$.
Let $ d = \gcd(\phi(m), m) < m$.
Then, by the induction hypothesis, there exists some $ a $ such that $ d \mid 3^{a+1} - 2^a  - a$.
Pick a $p$ such that $ b =  a + p d\phi(d) \geq \max (s, t)$. Consider the system
$$ \begin{cases} k \equiv b \pmod{\phi(m) } \\ k \equiv  3^{b+1} - 2^b \pmod{m } \end{cases} $$
Since $ 3^{b+1} - 2^b \equiv b \pmod{ \gcd ( \phi(m), m) }$, hence by Chinese remainder theorem, we have a solution to the system, which gives us
$$ 3^{k+1} - 2^k - k \equiv 3^{b+1} - 2^b - (3^{b+1} - 2^b) \equiv 0  \pmod{m} . $$
Furthermore, for any positive integer $q$,
$$ 3^{ k+ q m\phi(m) + 1 } - 2^{k+ q m\phi(m) } - (k+ q m\phi(m) ) \equiv 3^{k+1} - 2^k - k  \equiv 0 \pmod{m}. $$

I would have never thought of this (+1)!
